# How can I sort / specify separate storage locations for my audio files?

Tags: applications, music-player

So, this question is a little off the wall, so I'll first explain what I'm looking to do.

I have a bunch of MP3s from a 'Learn to Speak Japanese' program, and I'd like to listen to them on my phone while I'm in my car. Ideally though, I'd like to keep them in a separate music player app so that they're not linked to my Google Music or scrobbled to Last.fm. If possible, I'd want to be able to set a custom directory for the app to look for music in, so that I could keep my music and language-learning MP3s organized into their own directories.

Is there a music player app that does this, or am I asking for something too ridiculous? Should I just suck it up and use the default music player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MortPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=MortPlayer%20&c=apps) allows you to specify folders that should be read/ignored.

Note however, that if you use the default player, it will still scan and display the tracks. You might also consider adding the files into a playlist and then playing only that playlist, if you don't want other songs/files to be included.

Comment: Mort Player seems to be exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I was even able to hide the files from Google Music by putting a .nomedia file in the directory, which luckily (at least in in my case) Mort player ignores. Thanks!